# @transactional(readonly = true) Vs @transaction in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I know the use and the basic understanding behind both @transaction and `@transaction(readOnly=true)`.

But in my project, in one service I have used `@transaction(readOnly=true)` -->> where it did all CRUD operations. While in my another service it did not let me update the table. I have to remove "readOnly=true".

I simply don't understand how it is allowing in one service to do all the operations and in other does not. Is there something I am missing about the basic understanding of this concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s only a hint.the readOnly parameter doesn’t guarantee its behaviour, is only a hint that may or may not be taken into account.[Source](https://codete.com/blog/5-common-spring-transactional-pitfalls/)
This just serves as a hint for the actual transaction subsystem; it will not necessarily cause failure of write access attempts. A transaction manager which cannot interpret the read-only hint will not throw an exception when asked for a read-only transaction but rather silently ignore the hint.
 it’s closely related to the propagation setting. For example: for SUPPORT, readOnly flag won’t ever be used; for REQUIRES_NEW always; for REQUIRED it depends on whether we already are in the transactional context or not, etc.

Comment: Thanks for replying the query. That's really helpful for me for getting the basic understanding of this.